# Can I set intelliJ to highlight php coding style?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, psr-2

I used Pycharm a lot and it automatically highlighted not only syntax errors, but also coding style (PEP8).

Now I use IntelliJ with PHP plugin (it's basically PHPstorm) and I want it to tell me if my code is fitting PSR-2 style.

My PyCharm underscored even lacking space in a line like:

```
if a<3:
```

but would not underscore this:

```
if a < 3:
```

Is it possible in IntelliJ with PHP plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [CodeSniffer](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-php-code-sniffer-tool.html) and configure it with [PSR2](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/tree/master/CodeSniffer/Standards/PSR2) rules.